# Haskell: app build troubleshooting (docker primer)

Tags: haskell, docker, build, haskell-stack

How am I supposed to go about troubleshooting if an imported library won't build?

```
$ stack new any-tool simple
$ cd any-tool/
$ stack build
```

The boilerplate builds.

Adding `import Turtle` to `Main.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Turtle

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "hello world"
```

Adding `turtle` to `any-tool.cabal`:

```
....
executable any-tool
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , turtle
```

Won't build:

```
$ stack build
clock-0.7.2: configure
clock-0.7.2: build
hashable-1.2.6.1: download
hashable-1.2.6.1: configure
hashable-1.2.6.1: build
hashable-1.2.6.1: copy/register
Progress: 2/30
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package clock-0.7.2 using:
      /home/alexey/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/alexey/spaces/haskell/any-tool/.stack-work/logs/clock-0.7.2.log

...
```

Looks like no particular surprise: turtle has a couple of dozen dependencies, any incompatibility and there she goes. The question is, what is my next step?

Comment: Did you try reading the log file it said it wrote? What's in there?

Comment: Clock.hsc:44:0: warning: "hsc_alignment" redefined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Log is a bit longer, but still pleasantly short. A warning and an error, absolutely cryptic, if you ask me :) .

Comment: Are you using Arch? See [this github issues thread](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3507) that appeared when I searched your error message.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Arch :) . Thanks! Let me research it. Bugreport closed...

Comment: I tried it. The first part (your link) successful, but makes no difference. The second part (desbot) won't build. I have no idea why ncurses should make any difference, and how desbot is relevant.

Comment: Sounds like it's an issue with your dev environment then

Comment: `stack` provides sandboxed environment, or so they say. There should be a way to order the right thing. Is it so?

Comment: kind of? It's sandboxed away from other installations of GHC, but it's not going to set up your dev environment for you -- it's not a Docker container.

Comment: What constitutes "dev environment" (something all the sandboxes share)?

Comment: Since this a linker error, you could examine the intermediate (generated) files which actually produce the error (use `-keep-tmp-files`). But since you've already found people with this same problem (and potential solutions that haven't worked for you) your best is likely to post on those issue trackers and describe how the problem manifests on your machine. The `stack` people seem to be pretty adamant that this is an Arch issue, so I would begin there (after trying all of the different fixes people have posted in on the stack issue tracker, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better drain the swamp.

https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/08/stack-docker

https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration

https://hub.docker.com/r/fpco/stack-build

It took me just installing `docker` from the reps,

```
$  docker pull fpco/stack-build
...
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED SIZE
...
fpco/stack-build    latest              4e3c147fca48        4 months ago        4.3GB
...
```

and adding three lines to `stack.yaml` of my project:

```
docker:
  enable: true
  image: 4e3c147fca48
```

The image is not quite lightweight, but well worth it.

You can probably put the image name right into `stack.yaml` with impunity:

```
docker:
  enable: true
  repo: "fpco/stack-build"
```